# copy file to a vagrant remote environment

Tags: linux, shell, remote-access, vagrant, sshfs

I'm worknig on a remote codebase via [vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) development environment and I use [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) for mounting the remote point on my localhost as below:

```
sshfs hostname:vagrant_remotemountpoint mountpoint
```

To copy a file to the vagrant `vagrant_remotemountpoint` first I open the `mountpoint` via nautilus and then paste the file into it. Now I like to do this process using a shell command.

Anybody has done such an effort? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `cp somefile mountpoint` on shell? With sshfs, `mountpoint` should appear like a normal directory on your system.